# Ensure new Form is on top of the stack

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

In `WinForms` I need to ensure that newly opened `Form` is on top of the stack and does not hide behind `Form` that instantiated it. I do not want to use `TopMost` property as it forces new form to stay on top of all `Forms` opened by all running processes. I just need to have my new `Form` to open on top of all forms in **current** application.

Comment: You most likely use Window.Show or ShowDialog to display your windows. This should force that window to be foremost on the

Comment: What's the problem with calling `Show()` method of your forms?

Answer (score 1):

This method will check the current application OpenForms collection for a window with a title you pass in. It will activate the window if it is found, or have the window manager launch one.

Not sure how you plan on Z-Ordering your windows, but you could use the loop in the code and do something with each openform.

```
public void FindWindowOrMake(string theTitle) 
{
        var found = false;
        foreach (var openForm in Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>()
            .Where(openForm => openForm.Text.Equals(theTitle)))
        {
            found = true;
            openForm.Activate();
            break;
        }
        if (found) return;  // target found and activated
        // create new instance
        WinMgr.Create(theTitle);
 }
```